# Unique session between tabs?

Tags: c#, php, .net, vb.net, session

We have a custom session handler which stores a history of data for pages.  We have a requirement where we need to store and identify unique sessions for every tab/window.

For simplicity let's just say I need a unique string for each tab i.e.

- Window A - Tab 1 - ABCDEF
- Window A - Tab 2 - CDEFGH
- Window A - Tab 3 - EFGHIJ
- Window B - Tab 1 - GHIJKL
- Window B - Tab 2 - IJKLMN

I need these strings to be accessible immediately when any link is clicked or when any tab performs a postback.

We have an overly complication solution in place at the moment which generates these unique strings and saves them in the tab name and cookies and uses the window blur/focus events to determine when a page has been navigated away. It works well 'in the lab' but we do get problems with this 'in the wild'.

I guess the most 'reliable' way to do this would be to generate a unique string and place it on the querystring for every page and every URL on that page, that way it would be available immediately as you click on any link or post back, and you could move between tabs / windows freely. However that would take a significant rewrite and I wonder if I'm missing a more straightforward option.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Which technology are you using? Your tags are looking to me as if you didn't have made a decision yet, whether to develop in C# or PHP or something else. Also I can't think of an easy way of tracking whether a client opens the page in the same or a new window (the least is identical to opening in a new tab). I guess you would have to use JavaScript to check in which window you are.

Comment: "a unique string and place it on the querystring for every page and every URL on that page, that way it would be available immediately as you change tab" A page is not the same a a tab. You may open one page after the other in the same window or one may open every page in a new window.

Comment: The technology is not important. We primarily use C# but I'd be happy to consider any solution and adapt to my needs. We need a multi window AND multi tab solution, I thought that was clear from my question.

Comment: Definitely possible to create an new session variable with a unique ID each time the page is loaded, but if you want to detect page change in 1 tab VS page change in 2+ tabs, you might have to bring in some sort of Javascript plugin working in connection with PHP...

Comment: "a multi window AND multi tab solution" There is no difference from the documents/JavaScript point of view. A window is a window is a window – whether it is displayed as a tab doesn't matter.

Comment: Not all users appreciate that but yes that's the solution I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we found an ideal solution to this. We don't have 'unique' sessions between tabs, we have 'unique' sessions for every page, ignoring tabs entirely.

We still use the blur/focus events to handle which tab the user is currently on, but that is only used to provide tab specific navigation history and is nothing separate to the session handling.

This seems to work well for our needs.